# Semantic Mediawiki property calculation

Tags: properties, mediawiki, semantics

I installed the MediaWiki-extension Semantic MediaWiki recently. In this extension you can define properties. They are like categories for values. If I define two properties like this:

[[StartYear::2000]] [[EndYear::2005]]

Is it possible to make calculations based on these properties if I do a semantic search. For example:

{{#ask: [[Category:Project]] [[EndYear]] - [[StartYear]] = 5
}}

to get all projects with a duration of 5 years?

best, UP

Comment: I found out that you can assign datatypes to properties. In this case I assigned the datatype number to "EndYear" and "StartYear" but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, you can't do calculations in #ask queries, **but** you **can** do calculations, using the [ParserFunction](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions) `#expr:`.  It'd be, er, *complicated* to mix these together, but it should be possible.  Comment if you successfully try it, and if I get a chance, I'll edit this answer with whatever I find out.

Answer (score 2):

For this you would need to pre-process the interval for each project page.

If you are using a template, you can easily create do it with the following code:

```
[[Interval::{{#expr:{{{StartYear}}} - {{{EndYear}}}}}| ]]
```

Then you can query it this way:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Project]] [[Interval::5]]}}
```